# How to decrease time to calculate and to save?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with three sheets named: Predujam, OSTATAK NAKNADE, vlookup.

Predujam and OSTATAK NAKNADE contain vlookup/xlookup formula which pull data from the vlookup sheet.

All three sheets contain like 4000 lines of data, columns range is A:Q.

For Predujam I use this code to do calculation only in the rows where the changes occurred:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PREDUJAM").Range("A2:O5000")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
      Is Nothing Then

        Range("A" & Range(Target.Address).Row & ": O" & Range(Target.Address).Row).Calculate

    End If
End Sub
```

For OSTATAK NAKNADE same code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OSTATAK NAKNADE").Range("A2:O5000")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
      Is Nothing Then

        Range("A" & Range(Target.Address).Row & ": O" & Range(Target.Address).Row).Calculate

    End If
End Sub
```

In sheet vlookup, to calculate that sheet only when it is opened:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Worksheets("vlookup").Calculate
End Sub
```

In ThisWorkbook, code that stops automatic calculation:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False
End Sub
```

I want to calculate only in the rows where the changes occurred.

Problem: Saving takes 20-30 seconds, and calculation in rows where the changes occurred is also doing with some delay.

Is there is a better way?

Comment: There's nothing obviously "wrong" with your code.  FYI in any code in a worksheet module, you can use `Me` to refer to the sheet itself (so `Set KeyCells = Me.Range("A2:O5000")` for example).  Also `Range(Target.Address)` is just a long way of writing `Target`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a proper answer, but a comment doesn't afford me enough space to write all of this...

As someone using VBA you probably appreciate the value of variables, i.e.

- calculate *something* once,
- 'remember' it in a variable, and then
- you can reference that variable efficiently multiple times, rather than, inefficiently, recalculating the *something* afresh every time you need to use it

Helper cells in the user-interface, while much maligned, are the equivalent of variables in this regard, i.e.

- something is calculated once,
- 'remembered' in a designated cell, and then
- that cell can be referenced whenever the result is required, rather than having every formula that needs the result recalculate it from first principles.

Why am I rambling about this ? Given that you are setting Workbook calculation to manual, your file is obviously spending a lot of time calculating: if you **audit the formulae in the workbook** then you will likely find at least some calculations common to several formulae - if you extract these calculations to designated helper cells,  then you can improve performance by having those results calculated *only once*, and then just referenced from the 'old formulae' rather than having the calculations repeated *in each formula in which they currently occur*.